# How to download an MP3 track from a YouTube video

Tags: command-line, downloads, mp3, youtube, ffmpeg

There are several Q&A threads that explain how to download youtube videos using the terminal.

However, I would also like to learn how to extract the video's soundtracks as MP3 files--also using only the terminal.

Answers briefly explaining how to use `youtube-dl` or other similar utilities before explaining how to extract the MP3 would be ideal for the sake of having all the information in one place--even though this aspect has been covered in other posts.

Comment: In most cases you can download m4a or webm without conversion. This is an interactive script that will let you choose a specific 'rendition' such as audio-only, video-only, etc: `youtube-dl -F "$1" ;
read -p "Please enter the desired quality # " FORMAT ;
youtube-dl -f $FORMAT "$1"`

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this question because the linked question is quite different, doesn't have any answers and goes into a chain of duplicate questions that don't address audio extraction of Youtube videos.

Comment: Note: for MacPorts users who found this, use `sudo port install youtube-dl` to install `youtube-dl`.

Answer (score 705):

You can also download the mp3 directly from youtube without converting using ffmpeg

```
youtube-dl --extract-audio --audio-format mp3 <video URL>
```

From the online help:

```
-x, --extract-audio        convert video files to audio-only files (requires
                           ffmpeg or avconv and ffprobe or avprobe)
```

Bear in mind as well that youtube-dl defaults to using avconv so you should consider specifying either avconv or FFmpeg at the commandline . From the online help :

```
--prefer-avconv                  Prefer avconv over ffmpeg for running the
                                 postprocessors (default)
--prefer-ffmpeg                  Prefer ffmpeg over avconv for running the
                                 postprocessors
```

Further options for keeping the original video, adjusting the bitrate or quality of the audio and a few others can be seen by looking at `youtube-dl -h` .

Comment: youtube-dl <video URL> --audio-format mp3 does not download me as mp3!

Comment: if you look at the man pages, this option tells you you still have to download `ffmpeg`

Comment: it case of problems like this with youtube-dl:
`ERROR: Unable to download webpage: <urlopen error [Errno 8] _ssl.c:510: EOF occurred in violation of protocol>`

this helped me: http://askubuntu.com/questions/791969/error-while-using-youtube-dl

Comment: If you are using `zsh` or `Oh My Zsh` instead of `Bash`, then you might get an error saying "no matches found" - simply put the URL inside of quotes so: `youtube-dl --extract-audio --audio-format mp3 "<video URL>"` or `youtube-dl --extract-audio --audio-format mp3 '<video URL>'`.

Comment: Running `brew install youtube-dl && brew install ffmpeg` installs it for mac users.

Comment: This downloads a pre-existing mp3 from Youtube? As in Youtube generates its own mp3 for every video, and this is available to download? I just want to be clear, because I'm thinking of switching to this method (`--audio-quality 0` is about double the file size).

Comment: `-f bestaudio ` works the same as `--audio-quality 0`

Comment: No need to add `-f bestaudio`. From the [documentation](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#format-selection): _"By default youtube-dl tries to download the best available quality, i.e. if you want the best quality you don't need to pass any special options, youtube-dl will guess it for you by default."_

Comment: Here is a simple script to automate this https://github.com/rst0git/youtube-dl-mp3

Comment: brew install ffmpeg 
for "ffprobe/avprobe and ffmpeg/avconv not found"

Comment: [Have a better mp3 filename](https://askubuntu.com/a/1199994/349837) with `youtube-dl --output "%(title)s.%(ext)s" --extract-audio --audio-format mp3 --audio-quality 0`

Comment: The version in Ubuntu 16.04 didn't work (2020-03-25) but I downloaded the latest binary from github and it worked.

Comment: On Ubuntu 20.04: "no video formats found; please report this issue on https://yt-dl.org/bug". [You may need to install from source rather than use apt versions](https://askubuntu.com/a/1202606/208696)

Comment: Works well on my Mac. But i had to install ffmpeg from homebrew first. I also found out some video does not work. Youtube give error that it "unable to extract video data". No idea why. I tried on youtube-mp3 sites, it also failed but just that particular video.

Comment: I seem to get higher bitrate audio when passing `--audio-quality 0` than I do when I omit it.

Answer (score 77):

#### Downloading from youTube

Install [youtube-dl](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl) from the official repository in Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install youtube-dl
```

or [as official readme suggest](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl#installation) using `curl` or `wget`. This will let you upgrade with `sudo youtube-dl -U`

To download a video execute the following:

```
youtube-dl <url>
```

E.g

```
youtube-dl http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_z-hEyVQDRA
```

You can also specify other options

```
-b            Best quality
-m            Mobile version
-d            High Definition
-g            Don’t download, just show the url
-c            Resume download of a video which was interrupted before
-w            Don’t overwrite existing file
```

For complete list of switches execute `man youtube-dl` in terminal.

Information from  [here](http://www.absolutelytech.com/2010/06/26/howto-download-youtube-video-from-command-line-ubuntu/)

#### Converting to mp3

Now install [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) from the official repo.

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
```

Next have a look to make sure the flv file has downloaded from youtube by typing

```
ls *flv
```

This will list all the flv files you have. What you should see is a flv file with the same name as the 'v' component of the youtube url you downloaded.

E.g if you downloaded `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_z-hEyVQDRA` then you should have a file called `_z-hEyVQDRA.flv`

Next you need to copy that file name and then put it in an ffmpg command like

```
ffmpeg -i <file name>.flv -acodec libmp3lame <song name>.mp3
```

So for this example you would type

```
ffmpeg -i _z-hEyVQDRA.flv -acodec libmp3lame MasterOfPuppets.mp3
```

Once this has successfully completed you will now have the mp3 file you were after.

**Note**

- For cleanup you may want to type `rm _z-hEyVQDRA.flv` to get rid of the flv file that you no longer need.
- Information from [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=855433)

Comment: You may want to add converting to mp3 with ffmpeg or aconv.

Comment: One more, `-acodec liblamemp3` in the ffmpeg command line.

Comment: Yes you could force the codec to be sure, I have added this. You could also use `-ac 2 -ab 128k` to ensure it converts at 128k

Comment: Or just `youtube-dl -x "${URL}"`.

Comment: @NRoach44: it's "libmp3lame", not "liblamemp3"

Comment: Interesting, but why downloading all these video data when all you want is audio? @uniquerockrz solution seems pretty sane.

Comment: Using apt-get is almost guaranteed to get you an outdated version, which will often be a _broken_ version, because Youtube updates itself frequently. Use the manual install instructions from the official site for a version that will both work and update properly: http://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/download.html

Comment: INCORRECT: You can also specify other options

-b            Best quality
-m            Mobile version
-d            High Definition
-g            Don’t download, just show the url
-c            Resume download of a video which was interrupted before
-w            Don’t overwrite existing file

Comment: @ChangosMuertos Yeah this answer is outdated (it's from 5 years ago...). See the accepted answer.

Answer (score 12):

This question has been answered a lot, but I figured I would add something really useful.  This should honestly just be included aliases when you install the youtube-dl package in my opinion.

I add these to my .bashrc.  If I want to download a video as an mp3 I can do that, or download an entire playlist as mp3 I can use mp3p then the url to the playlist.

It is really simple and also respects YouTube's flood or bot protection by having a 30 second interval between downloads.  This will also help make sure your IP doesn't get banned.

```
# youtube-dl alias
mp3 () {
    youtube-dl --ignore-errors -f bestaudio --extract-audio --audio-format mp3 --audio-quality 0 -o '%(title)s.%(ext)s' "$1"
}

mp3p () {
    youtube-dl --ignore-errors --sleep-interval 30 -i -f bestaudio --extract-audio --audio-format mp3 --audio-quality 0 -o '%(playlist)s/%(playlist_index)s - %(title)s.%(ext)s' "$1"
}

dlv () {
    youtube-dl --ignore-errors -o '%(title)s.%(ext)s' "$1"
}

dlp () {
    youtube-dl --yes-playlist --ignore-errors --sleep-interval 30 -o '%(playlist)s/%(title)s.%(ext)s' "$1"
}
```

Answer (score 11):

For those of us who prefer a GUI interface, there is [YouTube to MP3](https://www.mediahuman.com/youtube-to-mp3-converter/) from MediaHuman.

**1. Installation**

You can do [direct downloads](https://www.mediahuman.com/download.html) for Ubuntu 16.04+ but I prefer the [repository](https://www.mediahuman.com/repository.html) because of automatic updates.

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 7D19F1F3
sudo add-apt-repository https://www.mediahuman.com/packages/ubuntu

sudo apt update
sudo apt install youtube-to-mp3
```

**2. Usage**

Search and open 'Youtube to MP3' via dash or another launcher. Copy the Youtube video URL from the browser to your clipboard and paste it into the application by clicking the 'Paste link' button on the top-left corner. See screenshot below.

The download and conversion will begin automatically and the audio saved in the Home folder under `/Music/Downloaded by MediaHuman`

[image: Youtube to MP3 main interface]

Comment: Finally, a great GUI for this! Works like a charm (Lubuntu 18.04). Grabs the YouTube thumbnail as artwork too. Great settings page with plenty of customizations if that's your thing. Thanks for sharing, great find.

Answer (score 7):

For this task, I use `youtube-dl` (w/ a dependency on `ffmpeg`) with the following options for best results. You can pass it an URL for a single song or even an entire playlist.

```sh
youtube-dl --prefer-ffmpeg --extract-audio --audio-format mp3 --audio-quality 0 --embed-thumbnail <VIDEO_SONG_OR_PLAYLIST_URL>
```

Breaking down the meaning of the supplied options:

- `--prefer-ffmpeg` — Tells `youtube-dl` to prefer `ffmpeg` (as opposed to `avconv`).
- `--extract-audio` — Extract the audio stream and discard the video.
- `--audio-format mp3` — Save the audio stream in mp3 format.
- `--audio-quality 0` — Save audio with highest quality possible. The possible values here are 0-9 (you can also pass explicit bitrate such as 128K). If you do not pass this option, youtube-dl uses a default value of 5, often resulting in lower quality audio than you will get with a value of 0.
- `--embed-thumbnail` — (Optionally) Embed the video thumbnail into the saved audio files as album art metadata (will be shown in media player applications).

Answer (score 3):

### 16.04 and later

I recommend using the youtube-dl snap package (`sudo snap install youtube-dl`) to download the mp3 components of YouTube videos, so that you don't get blocked from downloading from YouTube because your version of youtube-dl is not up-to-date.

Show a list of the available formats for a specific YouTube URL which I have denoted by `<video URL>` in the following line of code.

```
snap run youtube-dl -F <video URL>
```

Download the mp3 from a specific URL.

```
snap run youtube-dl -f your-choice-of-format --extract-audio --audio-format mp3 <video URL>
```

where `your-choice-of-format` is replaced by an  format integer number that is selected from the `audio only` results of `youtube-dl -F <URL>`. The `audio only` results of `youtube-dl -F <URL>` will show a choice of available bitrates (e.g. 192k) for you to choose from, but the `video only` results of `youtube-dl -F <URL>` cannot be saved by youtube-dl to any audio format.

Comment: Why wouldn't youtube-dl be up-to-date if [the official documentation](http://ytdl-org.github.io/youtube-dl/download.html) was followed? Updating with just `youtube-dl -U`. There is no need for snap.

Comment: @PabloBianchi The `youtube-dl -U` command doesn't always work properly in Ubuntu, and instead of updating youtube-dl it does nothing. Ubuntu users who encounter this problem can solve it by installing the youtube-dl snap package which is updated automatically usually to the latest version or if not to a recent version of youtube-dl. In general snap packages are automatically updated to newer versions than apt packages in Ubuntu which makes snap packages a good option for users who want the latest version of software.

Comment: Installed correctly (the official way, not with apt, which I didn't mention) `-U` should work (always worked for me), and if not, an issue should be filed. The only advantage could be containerization.

Answer (score 0):

In case you need a GUI for downloading Audios from Youtube only I'd like to introduce [YoutubeDownloader](https://github.com/kanehekili/YoutubeDownloader)

It has been written to ensure the best possible quality in combination. It provides a simple interface for downloading videos or audio tracks only. It has a GTK3 interface and was written for Linux/Ubuntu

[image]