# Error while using youtube-dl

Tags: youtube, youtube-dl, playlists

I am trying to download a playlist using youtube -dl but getting an error.

Command:

```
youtube-dl --playlist-start 1 https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL8B24C31197EC371C
```

Output:

```
    [youtube:playlist] PL8B24C31197EC371C: Downloading page #1
ERROR: Unable to download webpage: <urlopen error [Errno 8] _ssl.c:510: EOF occurred in violation of protocol>
```

What should i do?

Comment: Have you verified that you are using the most recent version of youtube-dl?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Yes. I have checked it.

Comment: @rohit15079 I can't reproduce your error; I was able to download the playlist. I installed `youtube-dl` using `pip` in a virtualenv for both Python 2 and 3 on a Ubuntu 16.04 machine.

Comment: @edwinksl how to do that?

Comment: @rohit15079 There are plenty of resources for learning how to install and use `pip` and `virtualenv`. There isn't enough space in a comment to show you how to do that.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**My fault:**

I installed youtube-dl using command : `sudo apt-get install youtube-dl`

**What should I have done:**

I should have used commands (either one):

either

```
sudo curl -L https://yt-dl.org/latest/youtube-dl -o /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
sudo chmod a+rx /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
```

or

```
sudo wget https://yt-dl.org/downloads/latest/youtube-dl -O /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
sudo chmod a+rx /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
```

I used the first one and then it worked correctly.

Comment: before you forget that path, you should alias it. Example: add
    alias youtube-dl='/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl' in your .bashrc

Comment: @augusto `/usr/local/bin` is usually in your $PATH, meaning that you don't need that alias to just run `youtube-dl something` from bash.