# error add alias youtube-dl='/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl' in your .bashrc

Tags: youtube, youtube-dl

this is with respect to 
[Error while using youtube-dl](https://askubuntu.com/questions/791969/error-while-using-youtube-dl)

while doing the below command on terminal:

```
add alias youtube-dl='/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl' in your .bashrc
```

got following message:

```
No command 'add' found, did you mean:
 Command 'ad' from package 'netatalk' (universe)
 Command 'atd' from package 'at' (main)
 Command 'adb' from package 'android-tools-adb' (universe)
 Command 'adb' from package 'adb' (universe)
 Command 'tdd' from package 'devtodo' (universe)
 Command 'ldd' from package 'libc-bin' (main)
 Command 'dd' from package 'coreutils' (main)
 Command 'axd' from package 'afnix' (universe)
 Command 'ddd' from package 'ddd' (universe)
 Command 'aid' from package 'id-utils' (universe)
 Command 'and' from package 'and' (universe)
 Command 'adbd' from package 'android-tools-adbd' (universe)
 Command 'amd' from package 'am-utils' (universe)
 Command 'hadd' from package 'root-system-bin' (universe)
add: command not found
```

what to do now ?

Answer (score 2):

The correct alias (as you describe) should be added to your .bashrc file if you enter the following into a terminal:

```
echo "alias youtube-dl='/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl'" >> ~/.bashrc
```

I'm also assuming this is unnecessary since anything in /usr/local/bin/ should be able to be accessed from the terminal anyway. Check that this is the case with the following:

```
which youtube-dl
```

If /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl returns as the answer, then the above is completely unnecessary, and you can ignore this step. However, if you want to customize youtube-dl so that everytime you run it, you [run it with "options"](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#description), you can add them to the previously created alias in your .bashrc file, such that anything you would type after youtube-dl gets placed before the last single-quote:

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```