# Difference b/w 'apt-get install' and 'curl -L https://...' and safety of each?

Tags: apt, curl

I'm sorry if this is a beginner question, but I did not find the answer elsewhere.

[Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/791969/error-while-using-youtube-dl) a user installed youtube-dl using apt-get install, but the program did not run without errors.

They said the solution was to install by using:

```
sudo curl -L https://yt-dl.org/latest/youtube-dl -o /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
sudo chmod a+rx /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
```

But the reason for the problem was not given, which leaves me confused.

So it appears that the first installs youtube-dl using Ubuntus standard repositories, and the second installs it directly from yt-dl.org.

But if this problem has been going on for months, why is it that youtube-dl is in the repositories and does not work? Am I not correct to be paranoid of installing things outside of Ubuntu's repositories?

Comment: Did the people involved file bug reports?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? Based on [the highest priority bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/youtube-dl/+bug/1529647) for that package in the Ubuntu repositories, maybe the newest versions haven't been backported for your version of Ubuntu.