# How to install aTube Cacher? in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, software-installation

Is it possible to install this program in the Ubuntu operating system?
What is the command line for this?

Comment: Could you at at least link the program you mean?

Comment: Well the official page shows that only is supported on Windows

Comment: All this does is download YouTube videos?

Comment: No, my job is download the audio from youtube videos. In other case what other tool can I use to do this ?

Comment: Is this what you need? http://askubuntu.com/questions/178481/how-to-download-an-mp3-track-from-a-youtube-video

Answer (score 1):

Referring to here: https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=9810

Seems like it doesn't work well with Wine, although results listed there are conflicting and old.

You can try, however. Install Wine:

```
sudo apt-get install wine
```

And try to run the aTube Catcher executable. It may or may not work.

Wine allows for some Windows programs to be run on Linux. However, aTube Catcher does not have native Linux support and you will have to run it via Wine.