# youtube-dl won't download mp3

Tags: youtube-dl

youtube-dl downloads neither videos nor mp3. This is the command I use:

```
youtube-dl --extract-audio --audio-format mp3 <Youtube URL>
```

The output:

> m62iekbg9eo: "token" parameter not in video info for unknown reason; please report this issue on https://yt-dl.org/bug . Make sure you are using the latest version; see  https://yt-dl.org/update  on how to update. Be sure to call youtube-dl with the --verbose flag and include its complete output.

The version is 2018.03.14. I upgraded it using pip and it said it is upgraded. But when I asked the version `youtube-dl --version`
 it still shows me 2018.03.14.

So I deleted youtube-dl and installed it again with pip. The commands I used:

```
sudo apt-get remove youtube-dl
sudo apt-get install python-pip  
pip install --user youtube-dl
```

But now, when I try to donwload an mp3 it says:

> bash: /usr/bin/youtube-dl: No such file or directory

Also I use 18.04.3 LTS

Comment: You haven't given your release details, nor if you actually installed the program using `apt` package tools if you removed it before using `python-pip` to upgrade/install it.    I suspect you've two versions installed; but it's unclear from your description.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove an youtube-dl packages from your system.

```
sudo wget https://yt-dl.org/downloads/latest/youtube-dl -O /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
sudo chmod a+rx /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
```

- First one draws the program from git, and saves the file under
  /usr/local/bin/
- Second one makes it executable.

This is the up-to-date version direct from git. From time to time you have to update the programm with

```
sudo youtube-dl -U
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem with a sligtly change on the command where /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl is simply /usr/bin/youtube-dl

Comment: You should let it in /usr/local/bin/ this is in your $PATH.

Comment: But it gives the same error: 

    bash: /usr/bin/youtube-dl: No such file or directory

Comment: Okay then make a softlink `sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl /usr/bin/youtube-dl` but /usr/local/bin should in your $PATH. `echo $PATH`

Comment: You just need to open a new terminal window and issue the youtube-dl command there, after uninstalling the apt version, to avoid the the path mangling issue

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest removing all `youtube-dl` packages from your system, so that when you run `youtube-dl` you will get *Command not found* error.

After that, run the command (as *root user* or prefixed with `sudo`):

```
 # pip install -U youtube-dl
```

It will install `youtube-dl` to path `/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl`.

**Note:** Before using `youtube-dl` in the future, run the above command to update it to the latest version.